# How to overload the Windows Explorer functionalities?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I want to catch the event of deletion, renaming or copying a file in Windows Explorer. For example, if a folder contains the files "**test.a**" and "**test.b**", and that I remove "**test.a**", then my program will remove the two (same for copy and rename).

I know how to add an entry to the context menu of Windows. But the goal isn't to add functionality to Windows. The goal is to redefine an existing function.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. Are you wanting to alter the functionality of the FileOpenDialog? Or an extension that changes what the Windows Explorer does?

Comment: No. Some standard formats save several files (one for the data for example and the others for metadata). But just the extansion change, not the name. My program copy, rename, or delete all the specific files when there is a copy, rename or delete one of theme. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [shell notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762120.aspx) APIs for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use hook for that. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank's for the answer. This hook is just for copy, I'll try this now !